# Working on a project where the PO/Customer is unbelievably unorganized and does not provide hardly any requirements

Tags: project-management, requirements

Little History,  I used to work directly for this company a few years back.  Due to budget reasons I decided I needed to move on.  however I maintained as a part time contractor to keep the lights on.  Within the last 6 months they asked me to contract full time complete a pilot program for a new product.

*I know the history of the company and really had low expectations when it comes to user stories and acceptance criteria.  I'm very familiar with the products and can generally work within these constraints effectively.*

TimeLine:

**December**: Start Date, was informed need to be pilot ready by Feb 01. We all agreed on the MVP model

**January**: MVP Model grew - I accepted the additional work.

**Feb**: Pilot delivered & customer using.

**Feb-March**: Iterate on feedback, no real issues & customers are very excited

**April**: Informed going full product release by July, worked on building out MVP model

**Mid April**: Complete 180 on MVP, customer decided in addition of a stand alone app for new customer base they want this fully integrated with another application.  It must work for both types of customers but no real context on what that means.

**Late April**: Customer wants other changes & another application to be modified and extended to facilitate integration.  Still waiting on user stories, criteria is trickling in but seems to change the scope of work when it does.

**Today**: Left trying to accommodate customers requests.  There's no business analyst or quality QA staff.  The client is way under resourced and can not effectively express any story board, user story or basic requirements.  Most of my time is spent in conversations probing for criteria.  When I present a complication and need rules or guidance on how they want it to work they shut down and get frustrated.

What can I do better to help my customer?

Comment: Walk away. Seriously. Spend your time working with people who don't get frustrated and shut down. They don't seem to have any clue on what they need, and the scope is out of control. Cut your losses.

Comment: You need to meet the customer at their level. If they are not familiar with user stories or technical requirements, you have to help them. Present a prototype of user interfaces on paper and walk them through it, and listen carefully to their feedback.

Comment: Thanks @jacquesB.  Good point here, they are agile certified and the po has scrum master certification.  That's not to say they understand, past projects were well documented with comprehensive user stories.  Unfortunately the individuals on that project are no longer with the company.

Comment: @DanWilson: nonsense - one does not solve problems by evading them. This is a great opportunity to charge the customer for the extra analysis work which needs to be done. This is only a question of making the right contract.

Comment: They get frustrated because they hired you to fill in the blanks, not for making them do your job. The situation sounds ideal, I'll take a project like that anytime. "Most of my time is spent in conversations probing for criteria". Yeah... So? This is normal at the start of any project. If you need user stories to feel comfortable I don't think anyone would object if you wrote them and used them to produce a project definition.

Comment: @DocBrown this doesn't sound like a problem that the OP can or *should* solve. There is dysfunction within the customer's organization that has caused employees (including the OP) to leave. Reworking the contract to include requirements analysis may increase OP's income, but the 180 on the MVP and desire to integrate with multiple other apps smells like chaos to me. I'm sure the customer would pay for the extra time, but I doubt there's any benefit for OP's career or fulfillment in doing so.

Comment: @DanWilson: maybe there is, maybe not, but you are clearly interpreting things into the question which are not written there (or at least can be interpreted differently). But I am here with Martin Maat - they hired the OP probably not just as a code monkey who waits until someone else presents them the perfectly written user stories or specs. If there is a business analyst missing in the company, the OP could take this role for a while. They should just make sure they get paid for the BA work, and have a contract which obligates the client to supprt them for this role.

Comment: ,,, but I agree: not every software engineer feels comfortable in the analysts role - so if that the OP does not like to go that route, you may be correct: the OP should better find a job which matches their expections more.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is not uncommon. In fact, in *most* projects the customer does not fully know up front what their exact requirements are. This is why the infamous Waterfall Model almost never works. In any real-world project you will have changing requirements and new discoveries during the development process. The process *has* to be able to accommodate it.

The responsibility for gathering requirements in a usable form falls on you. Books have been written about this topic, but one simple approache is sketching the UI on paper and walk the customer through it, listening very carefully to the feedback. With a paper UI you can change and refine it on the fly, so this is a very efficient process.

During development I would also recommend an iterative process where you continuously get feedback from the customer.

Always speak with the customer in a language they understand.

And be sure to change for time used, not a lump sum.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the iron rule: The customer is always right - if the customer pays. Now your job would be to bring them guidance. That needs to be agreed one level above your actual contacts, that they need to provide you with requirements and if they don’t, you can go to the person one level higher who tells them to help you.

But most important is that you’re paid for every hour of work. And if you work twice as much because the customer is ineffective, you make twice as much money.

Answer (score 0):

> January: MVP Model grew - I accepted the additional work.

This is when you messed up.  You created an expectation that the requirements can be changed at any point without impact to the delivery schedule.  Take this as a lesson for your next engagement.  You need to set up clear boundaries around how change requests will be accepted and how that will relate to delivery.  For example you might require that they timeline be extended or that some other requirement be dropped.  Once you've committed to something, you need to defend that commitment against scope creep, otherwise it will look like you are the problem.  If the client can't understand that, they are unreasonable and you probably should move on.

This might be a lost cause.  I would explain to the person who owns this i.e. the person with the budget (or if that's not possible, their surrogate) and explain the problem which is, if you aren't clear, that they cannot articulate what they want.  The most important factor in successful projects is knowing what you are trying to accomplish.  As an analogy, what they are doing here is like asking you travel somewhere and continually changing the destination as you are about to arrive.

This person might say they will resolve that and get you requirements.  If you can, I would suggest instead that you take what you have to this point and try to build a POC/demo of what it is that you think they want.  Then they will start telling you all the ways you went wrong.  Then you can work out an iterative delivery schedule.  But all this swirling gets them nothing.  It's better to have something that provides some value instead of a perfect solution that is never delivered.

I'm not sure how you are getting paid so that's a whole other set of potential issues.

Comment: @DocBrown I will clarify.  It's more than just cost (we don't know if this is fixed or T&M), it's impact on timeline.  These changes were accepted in the last month before the pilot delivery which appears to have been sufficient for the pilot but gives the impression it's OK to request change at any point.